# How to return all properties from Factory function

Tags: coffeescript

Considering the following constructor function, CoffeeScript compile in such a way that only the two functions at the end are returned.

How can I return every property so that I can directly access the properties of objects created using this factory?

```
createPerson = (firstName, lastName, age) ->
  firstName = firstName
  lastName = lastName
  age = age

  sayHi: ->
    console.log "Hi there"

  sayAge: ->
    console.log "My age is #{age}"
```

This is really easy to achieve using CoffeeScript's Class system but in this case I'm trying the simpler way and surprisingly failing to find a way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this out: http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/design_patterns/factory_method

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd just use a `class` in CoffeeScript rather than trying to do it yourself:

```
class Person
  constructor: (@firstName, @lastName, @age) ->
  sayHi: ->
    console.log "Hi there"
  sayAge: ->
    console.log "My age is #{@age}"
```

and then create new people with `new Person`:

```
p = new Person('Pancakes', 'McGee', 42)
```

Note the `@` for instance variables in both the constructor function definition and inside `sayAge`.

Comment: Im aware of the class functionality provided by CoffeeScript, although im exploring the basic methods available in javascript so I can further understand both. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify what you're trying to return. Odds are you'd do it exactly the same way you'd do it JavaScript.